# DMOS construction

Tags: cmos, circuit-design

[image]
I am learning for my exam , and i am not sure if this DMOS construction si correct. Did i make any mistake or is it as it should be?

Comment: Learn how to draw an OR/NOR gate first.

Comment: we were said we could just write name of operand but for education, how should they look?

Comment: @trolkura: The [Logic gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) page on Wikipedia has the symbols for two-input gates. It is unfortunate that you were taught that you do not need the shape; the correct shape is important.

Comment: And what about structure, its correct?

Comment: structure looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your circuit is a correct translation of the expression. here is an different circuit that gives the same result but uses only one type of gate.

Sometimes it is desirable to use several of the same type of gate for example if using 4000 series CMOS parts which typically have 4 gates of the same type

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyYFqU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>